# How to get a function name as a string?

Tags: python, string, function

How do I get a function's name as a string?

```
def foo():
    pass

>>> name_of(foo)
"foo"
```

Comment: `getattr(func, "__name__", str(func))` is what I use, in case it's a `Mock` (or some other object) that has no `__name__` attribute

Answer (score 1371, accepted):

```
my_function.__name__
```

Using `__name__` is the preferred method as it applies uniformly. Unlike `func_name`, it works on built-in functions as well:

```
>>> import time
>>> time.time.func_name
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in ?
AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'func_name'
>>> time.time.__name__ 
'time'
```

Also the double underscores indicate to the reader this is a special attribute. As a bonus, classes and modules have a `__name__` attribute too, so you only have remember one special name.

Comment: Because in some cases, you get some function object as an argument to your function, and you need to display/store/manipulate that function's name. Perhaps you're generating documentation, help text, a history of actions, etc. So no, you're not always hardcoding the function name.

Comment: @mgargiel: What I meant to say is: supposing you have a class which defines 100 methods, where all methods are only wrappers, which call a private method, passing the name of the wrapper itself. Something like this: ``def wrapper(kwargs): super(ExtendedClass,self).call('wrapper', kwargs)``. You have another choice, which is: ``def wrapper(kwargs): super(ExtendedClass,self).call(sys._getframe().f_code.co_name, kwargs)``. So, the answer from Albert Vonpupp looks better to me.

Comment: @RichardGomes One answer is appropriate for getting the name within the function itself, the other is appropriate for getting it from a function reference. The OP's question as written indicates the latter.

Comment: @RichardGomes Actually I came to this question looking for a solution to this problem. The problem I'm trying to address is create a decorator that can be used to log all my calls.

Comment: @RichardGomes functions are first-class objects, there can be more than name bound to them.  It is not necessarily the case that `f.__name__ == 'f'`.

Comment: I don't see this solution being of any help since most people would only use this if they want something generic that you can call as a method many times. Such a method would be good if you want to track the order of running functions. The solution above is saying my function is foo and calling foo._name__ and then setting it to a variable name. You might as well just set a string with the value foo. The _getframe() call described below as another solution works inside multiple functions inside one class! exactly what I needed.

Comment: @EamonnKenny I've written a decorator that takes a generic function as input.  Under certain cases, it raises an error if the method cannot be supported.  My exception reports back the unsupported method name in the exception message.  `__name__` solves this.

Comment: @RichardGomes my use case is for debugging a functional programming function. I have a function that accepts a function as an argument and I want to log the name of the function that was passed

Answer (score 425):

To get the current function's or method's name from inside it, consider:

```
import inspect

this_function_name = inspect.currentframe().f_code.co_name
```

`sys._getframe` also works instead of `inspect.currentframe` although the latter avoids accessing a private function.

To get the calling function's name instead, consider `f_back` as in `inspect.currentframe().f_back.f_code.co_name`.

---

If also using `mypy`, it can complain that:

> error: Item "None" of "Optional[FrameType]" has no attribute "f_code"

To suppress the above error, consider:

```
import inspect
import types
from typing import cast

this_function_name = cast(types.FrameType, inspect.currentframe()).f_code.co_name
```

Comment: +1: This is the answer I'd like to see. Other answers assume that the caller already knows the function name, which is nonsense in the context of this question.

Comment: Richard: no it doesn't. YOU are assuming that you're calling __name__ or func_name on your function directly in the same scope it was defined, which very often isn't the case. Keep in mind that functions are objects - they can be passed around as arguments to other functions, stored in lists/dicts for later lookups or execution, etc.

Comment: @paulus_almighty, digging into stack frames doesn't strike me as abstract! In fact, it's kind of the opposite of abstract. See the [implementation detail](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys._getframe) note in the docs. Not all implementations of Python will include `sys._getframe` -- it's directly connected to the internals of CPython.

Comment: This only works inside the function, but the question specifies that the function shouldn't be called.

Comment: Case you wanna wrap your function to something more usable and easy to remember u have to retrieve frame 1 like `sys._getframe(1).f_code.co_name`, so you can define a function like `get_func_name()` and expect to get the desired name of the function who invoked.

Comment: @Igor, `sys._getframe()`, gets a n frame, case of `sys._getframe(1)` will take a "one deep level" frame from the list/stack. So, if you wrap the call between a class->function->function, you'll need to pass the number of functions/classes that has called it. It's a bit weird, but simple. In a single and direct call, doing `sys._getframe()` means `sys._getframe(0)`, and cuz it was not explictly told u can't guess magically that you can pass numbers. You're welcome.

Comment: piggybacking on this answer: the raiseValueError line is a universal docstring caller! You do not need to type the function name!: line 1: `if not some_input:`
line 2 `....raise ValueError(f'No input received. \n\t{eval(inspect.currentframe().f_code.co_name).__doc__}')`

Answer (score 53):

If you're interested in class methods too, Python 3.3+ has `__qualname__` in addition to `__name__`.

```
def my_function():
    pass

class MyClass(object):
    def method(self):
        pass

print(my_function.__name__)         # gives "my_function"
print(MyClass.method.__name__)      # gives "method"

print(my_function.__qualname__)     # gives "my_function"
print(MyClass.method.__qualname__)  # gives "MyClass.method"
```

Comment: If method has the @property decorator, this does not work, any way to access the name in this instance?

Comment: @dusiod, looks like you can get the name/qualname from the property's getter (which you create using the @property decorator): `MyClass.prop.fget.__qualname__` gives `MyClass.prop`.

Answer (score 47):

```
my_function.func_name
```

There are also other fun properties of functions. Type `dir(func_name)` to list them. `func_name.func_code.co_code` is the compiled function, stored as a string.

```
import dis
dis.dis(my_function)
```

will display the code in *almost* human readable format. :)

Comment: What is the difference between f.__name__ and f.func_name?

Comment: double underscore names are traditionally regarded as private though never enforced.  So it is better to use func_name even though they may be the same.

Comment: Sam: __names are private, __names__ are special, there's a conceptual difference.

Comment: In case someone is puzzled by the preceding answer by Matthew, the comment system has interpreted some double-underscores as code for bold. Escaped with backtick, the message should read: `__names__` are private, `__names` are special.

Comment: @MatthewTrevor, do you have a reference for more information/specifics?

Comment: Actually, I think the correct is `_names` are private (single underscore before, just a convention), `__names__` are special (double underscores before and after). Not sure if double underscore before has any meaning, formally or as a convention.

Comment: @MestreLion It's called [name mangling](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#private-variables-and-class-local-references).

Comment: @nyuszika7h: true, I forgot about name mangling. So I guess the best advise is: use the *convention* `_name` for "ordinary" private members, as `__name` is subject to name mangling and `__name__` may be "special" depending on `name`, unless either are what you want and you know what you're doing.

Comment: `func_name` doesn't exist any more in python3 so you need to use `func.__name__` if you want compatibility

Answer (score 40):

```
import inspect

def foo():
   print(inspect.stack()[0][3])
```

where

- `stack()[0]` is the caller
- `stack()[3]` is the string name of the method

Comment: Plain and simple. `stack()[0]` will always be the caller, `[3]` the string name of the method.

Answer (score 39):

This function will return the caller's function name.

```
def func_name():
    import traceback
    return traceback.extract_stack(None, 2)[0][2]
```

It is like Albert Vonpupp's answer with a friendly wrapper.

Comment: I had "<module>" at index [2], but the following worked: traceback.extract_stack(None, 2)[0][-1]

Comment: for me this doesn't work, but this does: traceback.extract_stack()[-1][2]

Comment: This works if change the first index to 1, you folks should learn to debug before commenting...

traceback.extract_stack(None, 2)[1][2]

Answer (score 29):

I  like using a function decorator.
I added a class, which also times the function time. Assume gLog is a standard python logger:

```
class EnterExitLog():
    def __init__(self, funcName):
        self.funcName = funcName

    def __enter__(self):
        gLog.debug('Started: %s' % self.funcName)
        self.init_time = datetime.datetime.now()
        return self

    def __exit__(self, type, value, tb):
        gLog.debug('Finished: %s in: %s seconds' % (self.funcName, datetime.datetime.now() - self.init_time))

def func_timer_decorator(func):
    def func_wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        with EnterExitLog(func.__name__):
            return func(*args, **kwargs)

    return func_wrapper
```

so now all you have to do with your function is decorate it and voila

```
@func_timer_decorator
def my_func():
```

Answer (score 23):

You just want to get the name of the function here is a simple code for that.
let say you have these functions defined

```
def function1():
    print "function1"

def function2():
    print "function2"

def function3():
    print "function3"
print function1.__name__
```

the output will be **function1**

Now let say you have these functions in a list

```
a = [function1 , function2 , funciton3]
```

to get the name of the functions

```
for i in a:
    print i.__name__
```

the output will be

**function1**
**function2**
**function3**

Answer (score 21):

As an extension of [@Demyn's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20714270/109941), I created some utility functions which print the current function's name and current function's arguments:

```
import inspect
import logging
import traceback

def get_function_name():
    return traceback.extract_stack(None, 2)[0][2]

def get_function_parameters_and_values():
    frame = inspect.currentframe().f_back
    args, _, _, values = inspect.getargvalues(frame)
    return ([(i, values[i]) for i in args])

def my_func(a, b, c=None):
    logging.info('Running ' + get_function_name() + '(' + str(get_function_parameters_and_values()) +')')
    pass

logger = logging.getLogger()
handler = logging.StreamHandler()
formatter = logging.Formatter(
    '%(asctime)s [%(levelname)s] -> %(message)s')
handler.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(handler)
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

my_func(1, 3) # 2016-03-25 17:16:06,927 [INFO] -> Running my_func([('a', 1), ('b', 3), ('c', None)])
```

Answer (score 19):

`sys._getframe()` is not guaranteed to be available in all implementations of Python ([see ref](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html)) ,you can use the `traceback` module to do the same thing, eg.

```
import traceback
def who_am_i():
   stack = traceback.extract_stack()
   filename, codeline, funcName, text = stack[-2]

   return funcName
```

A call to `stack[-1]` will return the current process details.

Comment: Sorry, if `sys._getframe()` is undefined, then `traceback.extract_stack` is also inoperable.  The latter provides a rough superset of the functionality of the former; you cannot expect to see one without the other.  And in fact, in IronPython 2.7 `extract_stack()` always returns `[]`.  -1

Answer (score 16):

I've seen a few answers that utilized decorators, though I felt a few were a bit verbose. Here's something I use for logging function names as well as their respective input and output values. I've adapted it here to just print the info rather than creating a log file and adapted it to apply to the OP specific example.

```
def debug(func=None):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        try:
            function_name = func.__func__.__qualname__
        except:
            function_name = func.__qualname__
        return func(*args, **kwargs, function_name=function_name)
    return wrapper

@debug
def my_function(**kwargs):
    print(kwargs)

my_function()
```

Output:

```
{'function_name': 'my_function'}
```

Comment: What I like about this as opposed to all the others, is that by just adding the `debug` function once you can add the functionality by simply adding the decorator to whatever function you need or want to print the function name. It's seems to be the easiest and the most adaptable.

Comment: Why is the try/except needed? When is `__qualname__` available directly and when it is not?

Answer (score 11):

```
import inspect

def my_first_function():
    func_name = inspect.stack()[0][3]
    print(func_name)  # my_first_function
```

or:

```
import sys

def my_second_function():
    func_name = sys._getframe().f_code.co_name
    print(func_name)  # my_second_function
```

Answer (score 10):

You can get a function's name as a string by using the special `__name__` variable.

```py
def my_function():
    pass

print(my_function.__name__) # prints "my_function"
```

Comment: This is new right? When did it come to be?

Comment: @Beefy_Swain the `__name__` special variable has been a part of the language since at least Python 2.0 (released in 2000) and likely dates as far back as the late 90s.

Answer (score 5):

Try

```py
import sys
fn_name = sys._getframe().f_code.co_name
```

further reference
https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/python-cookbook/0596001673/ch14s08.html