# How to print the function name as a string in Python from inside that function

Tags: python

```
def applejuice(q):
   print THE FUNCTION NAME!
```

It should result in "applejuice" as a string.

Comment: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18584/how-to-ask-a-smart-question-on-so/25128#25128

Comment: From the answer you chose we can conclude that this was indeed a duplicate. Indeed, a question almost exactly the same name already existed: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/251464/how-to-get-the-function-name-as-string-in-python

Comment: I disagree that this is a duplicate of #251464 -- it seems like this question is the inverse instead.

Comment: What should it print in this case :

     `def applejuice():  print "thefunctionname"; orangejuice = applejuice; del applejuice;   orangejuice();`

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This also works:

```
import sys

def applejuice(q):
    func_name = sys._getframe().f_code.co_name
    print func_name
```

Answer (score 11):

```
def applejuice(**args):
    print "Running the function 'applejuice'"
    pass
```

or use:

```
myfunc.__name__

>>> print applejuice.__name__
'applejuice'
```

Also, see [how-to-get-the-function-name-as-string-in-python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/251464/how-to-get-the-function-name-as-string-in-python)

Comment: this isn't from inside the function

Answer (score 8):

```
import traceback

def applejuice(q):
   stack = traceback.extract_stack()
   (filename, line, procname, text) = stack[-1]
   print procname
```

I assume this is used for debugging, so you might want to look into the other procedures offered by the [`traceback` module](http://docs.python.org/library/traceback.html). They'll let you print the entire call stack, exception traces, etc.

Answer (score 3):

Another way

```
import inspect 
def applejuice(q):
    print inspect.getframeinfo(inspect.currentframe())[2]
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to explain what your problem is. Because the answer to your question is:

```
print "applejuice"
```

Comment: maybe he means:  def func(anothah_func): print anothah_func's name

Comment: Well, that's definitely possible. We'll see if he says what the problem is.

Answer (score 1):

This site gave me a decent explanation of how sys._getframe.f_code.co_name works that returns the function name.

http://code.activestate.com/recipes/66062-determining-current-function-name/

Comment: Wlecome to SO! please, think about providing explanation, and not only pointing to external links.

Answer (score 0):

```
def foo():
    # a func can just make a call to itself and fetch the name
    funcName = foo.__name__
    # print it
    print 'Internal: {0}'.format(funcName)
    # return it
    return funcName

# you can fetch the name externally
fooName = foo.__name__
print 'The name of {0} as fetched: {0}'.format(fooName)

# print what name foo returned in this example
whatIsTheName = foo()
print 'The name foo returned is: {0}'.format(whatIsTheName)
```