# getting object name and function name

Tags: python

It is actually 2 questions. 
1) Is there a generic way to get the class name of an instance, so if I have a class

```
class someClass(object):
```

I would like a built in way that gives me a string 'someClass'

2) Similar with functions. If I have

```
def someFunction():
    ....
    print builtinMethodToGetFunctionNameAsString
    return
```

it would print 'someFunction'

The reason why I am looking for this is, that I have a bit of a jungle of classes and subclasses and for debugging I would like to print where I am, so to all methods I would just want to add something along the lines

```
print 'Executing %s from %s' %(getFunctionName,getClassName)
```

So I am looking for a generic command that know the class and the function where it is, so that I can copy and paste the line in all the methods without having to write a separate line for each of them

Comment: How about using a debugger?

Comment: use .format instead of % 'Executing {} from {}'.format(getFunctionName, getClassName)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

use the `__name__` attribute:

Class:

```
>>> class A:pass
>>> A.__name__
'A'
>>> A().__class__.__name__       #using an instance of that class
'A'
```

Function:

```
>>> def func():
...     print func.__name__
...     
>>> func.__name__
'func'
>>> func()
func
```

A quick hack for classes will be:

```
>>> import sys
>>> class A():
...     def func(self):
...         func_name = sys._getframe().f_code.co_name
...         class_name = self.__class__.__name__
...         print 'Executing {} from {}'.format(func_name, class_name)
...         
>>> A().func()
Executing func from A
```

Comment: Thanks Ashwini.
For the function, I am looking for a way to print the name without spepcifying the function. Edited my question to explain what my purpose is

Answer (score 3):

the function part has already been answered at [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1540177/how-to-print-the-function-name-as-a-string-in-python-from-inside-that-function). The code would be:

```
import sys
print sys._getframe().f_code.co_name
```

For the class part, use: `A.__name__` or `A().__class__.__name` (for an instance)