# python unittest: can't call decorated test

Tags: python, unit-testing, decorator

I have a pretty large test suite and I decorated some of the test_* functions. Now I can't call them by `./test.py MySqlTestCase.test_foo_double`, python3.2 complains that: `ValueError: no such test method in <class '__main__.MySqlTestCase'>: result`. My decorator code looks like this:

```
def procedure_test(procedure_name, arguments_count, returns):

    '''Decorator for procedure tests, that simplifies testing whether procedure
    with given name is available, whether it has given number of arguments
    and returns given value.'''

    def decorator(test):
        def result(self):
            procedure = self.db.procedures[self.case(procedure_name)]
            self.assertEqual(len(procedure.arguments), arguments_count)
            self.assertEqual(procedure.returns, 
                             None if returns is None else self.case(returns))
            test(self, procedure)
        return result
    return decorator
```

and the test method:

```
@procedure_test('foo_double', 0, 'integer')
def test_foo_double(self, procedure):
    self.assertEqual(procedure.database, self.db)
    self.assertEqual(procedure.sql, 'RETURN 2 * value')
    self.assertArguments(procedure, [('value', 'int4')])
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the problem is that the decorated function doesn't have the same name and, also, it doesn't satisfy the pattern to be considered a test method.

Using `functools.wrap` to decorate `decorator` should fix your problem. More information [here](http://docs.python.org/library/functools.html).

Answer (score 2):

This is a simple way of solving this issue.

```
from functools import wraps

def your_decorator(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(self):
        #Do Whatever
        return func(self)
    return wrapper

class YourTest(APITestCase):
    @your_decorator
    def example(self):
        #Do your thing
```

Answer (score 1):

This help me:

```
from functools import wraps
```

...

```
@wraps(procedure_name)
def decorator(test):
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/255297/1906088) post:

You can do it this way:

```
def decorator(test):
    def wrapper(self):
        # do something interesting
        test(self)
        # do something interesting
    wrapper.__name__ = test.__name__
    return wrapper
```

This solution has two advantages over method with `@functools.wrap`:

- doesn't need anything to import
- doesn't need to know test name when decorator is created

Thanks to the second feature of this solution, it is possible to create decorators for many tests.

Comment: This is the head-shot that kill the issue by 1 single blow. Must be the accepted one to me.

Comment: Note that functools.wraps does more than just setting name, such as docstring preservation. And the normal use of `wraps` in a decorator is
```
def decorator(func):
    @wraps(func)
    wrapper(*args)
    ...
````
Which can similarly wrap arbitrarily-named test cases.