# Django Testing: Using a login decorator for test cases

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, authentication, decorator

I've got a problem using a login decorator in my django tests. Many tests start with

```
self.client.login(username='foo', password='bar')
```

So, the login works in principle; But now I like to refactor this line of code into a decorator `login`, just for fun:

```
def login(fn):
    def wrapper(self):
        self.client.login(username='foo', password='bar')
        return fn(self)
    return wrapper
```

But the then failing tests show me that the user 'foo' is not logged in even `self.client.login` returns True.

One more mysterious thing is, when I now leave `self.client.login` from the decorator such that the decorator does nothing but wrapping, a normal login from within the decorated test method is then not possible anymore also!

I think there is some context or scope problem with the test client. Have you any idea what the probem can be? P.S.: The story is all about python2.7 and django-1.3.1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please see [python-unittest-cant-call-decorated-test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6312167/python-unittest-cant-call-decorated-test)

ALTERNATIVES?

Since it was always the same user, I had it in the setUp.

```
class SimpleTest(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.client.login(username='foo', password='bar')
```

Here is an interesting [gist - Lazy man's Django testcase](https://gist.github.com/1363418) that allows scoped logins.