# __name__ attribute in Python for Win32_ComputerSystem?

Tags: python, winapi, attributes, wmi, pywin32

I'm trying to get the name of a WMI win32 class. But the `__name__` attribute is not defined for it.

```
>> import wmi
>> machine = wmi.WMI()
>> machine.Win32_ComputerSystem.__name__
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#21>", line 1, in <module>
    machine.Win32_ComputerSystem.__name__
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\wmi.py", line 796, in __getattr__
    return _wmi_object.__getattr__ (self, attribute)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\wmi.py", line 561, in __getattr__
    return getattr (self.ole_object, attribute)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py", line 457, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(attr)
AttributeError: __name__
```

I thought that the `__name__` attribute is [defined for all Python functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/251464/how-to-get-the-function-name-as-string-in-python), so I don't know what the problem is here. How is it possible that this function doesn't have that attribute?

OK, The reason that I thought it was a method is because machine.Win32_ComputerSystem() is defined, but I guess that isn't enough for something to be a method. I realise that it isn't a method.

However, this doesn't work:

```
>> machine.Win32_ComputerSystem.__class__.__name__
'_wmi_class'
```

I want it to return 'Win32_ComputerSystem'. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I can tell looking at [the documentation](http://timgolden.me.uk/python/wmi/tutorial.html) (specifically, based on [this snippet](http://timgolden.me.uk/python/wmi/tutorial.html#determing-available-methods)), `wmi.Win32_ComputerSystem` is a class, not a method. If you want to get its name you could try:

```
machine.Win32_ComputerSystem.__class__.__name__
```

Comment: Yeah, that's not a function, it's an instance of an old-style class.

Comment: That just returns the generic '_wmi_class'

Answer (score 1):

I've found a way to get the output that I want, however it doesn't satisfy me.

```
repr(machine.Win32_ComputerSystem).split(':')[-1][:-1]
```

returns: `'Win32_ComputerSystem'`

There must be a more Pythonic way to do this.