# Python: some "__magic__" attribute to reference a function from within that function

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is there an analog of PHP's `__FUNCTION__` magic constant in Python?

```
def func(x):
    print(__FUNCTION__)  ## <function func at 0x00B02810>
    print(__FUNCTION__.__name__)  ## func
```

**UPD:**

To have an example:

```
import sys

def func(f = "Foo"):
    b = "Bar"
    print(sys._getframe().f_code) ## <code object func at 0x00B09A20, file "C:\py\func.py", line 5>
    print(func.__code__) ## <code object func at 0x00B09A20, file "C:\py\func.py", line 5>, the same

    print(sys._getframe().f_trace) ## None
    print(sys._getframe().f_locals) ## {'b': 'Bar', 'f': 'Foo'}
    print(sys._getframe().f_lineno) ## 12

if __name__ == "__main__":
    func()
```

Comment: Out of interest, why do you want to do this?

Comment: @Lattyware, in PHP I often used `__FUNCTION__`, `__METHOD__`, `__CLASS__` to create smth like flags to see in which component smth happened. As now I learn Python and have been testing function decorators I wanted to use the same technic to see what function have been called.

Answer (score 3):

You can get some of this functionality using the [inspect module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/inspect.html).

```
import inspect

def foo():
    code = inspect.currentframe().f_code
    print code.co_name
```

You could also execute the code from the code object using `exec code` where `code` is the variable created in the function above.

Note that `inspect.currentframe()` gives you the same object as `sys._getframe(0)`, but it is actually meant to be used this way.

Comment: *but it is actually meant to be used this way*. No, the `inspect` module provides friendlier spellings of the same tasks; the same caveats apply.

Comment: +1 Is there something equivalent to get the name of an instance ?

Answer (score 2):

There isn't any such functionality in Python.

You *could* abuse the [`sys._getframe()` function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys._getframe) to get access to the current code object though:

```
import sys

def foo():
    print sys._getframe(0).f_code.co_name
```

but that will only print the name of the function as it was defined originally. If you assign the `foo` function to another identifier, the above code will continue to print `foo`:

```
>>> bar = foo
>>> bar()
'foo'
```

Comment: +1 Is there something equivalent to get the name of an instance ?

Comment: @eyquem: That is much harder; you can introspect the code object of the current frame for a first argument to the function that happens to be a custom class instance (if it is called `self` so much the better). This is not failproof however.

Comment: Thank you. I will explore these possibilities some day

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you are after?

```
In [97]: def a():
    ...:     print sys._getframe().f_code.co_name
    ...:     

In [98]: a()
a
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/251464/how-to-get-the-function-name-as-string-in-python)

Comment: +1 Is there something equivalent to get the name of an instance ?