# Python Concatenate String and Function

Tags: python, string, function

Is there a way in Python to cat a string and a function?

For example

```
def myFunction():
    a=(str(local_time[0]))
    return a

b="MyFunction"+myFunction
```

I get an error that I cannot concatenate a 'str' and 'function' object.

Comment: Did you want to use the *return value* of `myFunction()` here?

Comment: If you are trying to just use the name, you could use `__name__` with myFunction and then concatenate them. (http://stackoverflow.com/a/255297/758446)

Answer (score 15):

There are two possibilities:

If you are looking for the return value of `myfunction`, then:

```
print 'function: ' + myfunction()
```

If you are looking for the name of `myfunction` then:

```
print 'function: ' + myfunction.__name__
```

Comment: I want to cll the function like b="MyFunction"+myFunction(), sorry, I missed the () above.  I am used to C++.  I want to run the function in the statement declaring b, is that possible?  I can do it if I run myFunction() outside of declaring b but I want to do it during that declaration, is it possible in python?

Comment: Calling the function will return a string. See the code here: http://ideone.com/UCUMgO.

Answer (score 3):

You need to call your function so that it actually returns the value you are looking for:

```
b="MyFunction"+myFunction()
```

Comment: When I do that I ger the error that I cannot concatenate a 'str' and 'function' object.

Comment: @user2295959, it worked for me... Did you notice the parenthesis?

Answer (score -1):

You can use

```
var= "string" + str(function())
```

example

```
a="this is best"
s="number of chars. in a " + str(len(a))
print(s)
```