# How do I get the name of a python definition

Tags: python, function, predefined-variables

it's possible to get in python 2.7.3 the name of a definition like this:

```
def Newname(self):
    print name_of_def

> "Newname"
```

Thx,

pux

Comment: Why would you do this? The name is right there. Just `print "Newname"`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/251464/how-to-get-the-function-name-as-string-in-python

Comment: @Claus: Different question. That one's about getting the name from outside the function, given the function object.

Comment: @user2357112: I'd say the question I linked is more general than this one. If you have a look at the answers to it, you'll see that both cases are mentioned.

Answer (score 5):

```
import sys

def newname():
    print sys._getframe().f_code.co_name

newname()
```

Answer (score 3):

```
import inspect

def Newname():
    return inspect.stack()[0][3]
```

Comment: I like this better than the sys._getframe call.  seems cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

use `__name__`

```
def Newname():
    return 0

print Newname.__name__
```

Comment: Nice try, but see the above comments to this question (by Claus and user2357112).

Comment: @JohnY: You could still print the function's name inside the function and have exactly what the OP asked for.