# Python print name of a unit test function in setup

Tags: python, unit-testing

After reading
[How to get the function name as string in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/251464/how-to-get-the-function-name-as-string-in-python)

I wondered if it is somehow possible to put a logging statement into one of the

```
def setUp(self):
    ... 

def tearDown(self):
    ...
```

and print the name of the current test function.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Testcases have a `self.id()` method that returns the current `TestClassName.testMethodName`.

[The method](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3f8b801e7e76/Lib/unittest/case.py#l264) uses `self._testMethodName` to build that string; you could use that attribute but the name of the attribute does flag it as internal. Relying on the attribute being there may not work in all Python versions.