# How to print a dictionary which has function names in it?

Tags: python, function, dictionary, printing

I want to print function names using this dictionary-

```
def pressKey() :
    print "is pressed"  
def userLogin() :
    print "Code to login to <Server Name> with <username>"
act={'Login':userLogin,'press':pressKey}
```

I tried via this (took from an answer)

```
for key, value in act.iteritems() :
    print value,'()\t',
    act[key]()
```

The function is being called (the second line of the loop)
but this code gives the output as-

```
<function pressKey at 0x0000000002F2DC88> ()    is pressed

<function userLogin at 0x00000000039BAEB8> ()   Code to login to <Server Name> with <username>
```

And i want the output as-

```
pressKey()    ispressed
userLogin()    Code to login to <Server Name> with <username>
```

Please help how can i get that !.Thanking you in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get a function name as a string in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/251464/how-to-get-a-function-name-as-a-string-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

If you know that they are all functions you could use the `__name__` attribute to get the name of the function:

```
for key, value in act.iteritems():
    print value.__name__, '()\t', 
    act[key]()
```

note that you actually don't need `key` since you could use `value()` instead of `act[key]()` which is also slightly more efficient:

```
for value in act.itervalues() :
    print value.__name__, '()\t',
    value()
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
def pressKey() :
    print "is pressed"  
def userLogin() :
    print "Code to login to <Server Name> with <username>"
act={'Login':userLogin,'press':pressKey}
for key, value in act.iteritems() :
    print value.__name__,'()\t',
    act[key]()
```