# Python Calling a Function Name as a Variable

Tags: python, python-3.x, formatting

I have a basic sort and search loop. At the end I want to thank the user and display the name of the function used. Is there a `format` call for doing this?

```
def arr_sort_binsearch(ar):

    item = 8

    ar.sort()
    l=0
    r=len(ar)-1

    while l<r:
        if (ar[l] + ar[r] == item):
            print("{} and {} is: {}".format(ar[l],ar[r],item))
            l += 1
            r -= 1
        elif (ar[l] + ar[r] < item):
            l += 1
        else:
            r -+ 1
    print("Thanks for using {}".format(name_of_function?)
```

Comment: If you had a function variable and wanted to know its definition name, you could use `f.__name__`. But if you mean the function you're in right now, why not just write `"Thanks for using arr_sort_binsearch"` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here ya go:

[How to get a function name as a string in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/251464/how-to-get-a-function-name-as-a-string-in-python)

Replace "name_of_function?" with:

```
arr_sort_binsearch.__name__
```

Comment: I knew it was something simple!

Comment: I'm glad it worked! Would you mind selecting my answer please?

Comment: If you are posting a link to an existing question, you should have marked this as a duplicate instead of posting an answer.