# How to get the full name of a method passed through as parameter

Tags: python, object, methods, parameters

I'm not sure if this is a duplicate question. I was reading information online (including here, e.g. [How to get a function name as a string in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/251464/how-to-get-a-function-name-as-a-string-in-python)) and messing around with the various suggestions, but the various information is either outdated/not for my specific use case/I am simply implementing it incorrectly.

The problem:

I'm passing the method of an object as a parameter. I would like to know what the full name of this object and method is.

Example code (where I'm am at thus far):

```
class test():
  def asdf():
    print('asdf')

def magic(command):
  print('command is:', command.__name__)

magic(test.asdf)
```

The goal would be to go from having magic() outputting 'command is: asdf' to 'command is: test.asdf' since that's the full name of the parameter.

Comment: Objects generally don't have names.

Comment: post code, not images of code.

Comment: What is the name of an object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `__qualname__`.

```
>>> print(test.asdf.__qualname__)
test.asdf
```

Comment: This only applies to the very specific case of an unbound method of a class. If I do something like `x = "asdf"; print(x.lower.__qualname__)`, I'm not going to get `x.lower`.

Comment: In general, this will fail for all instance methods.

Answer (score 1):

Just to be clear, you are not passing the "method of an object as parameter" but just a function name that is inside a class definition.

To pass a "method of an object" you have to actually create an object and the code would look like this:

```
class test():
  def asdf():
    print('asdf')

def magic(command):
  print('command is:', command.__func__.__qualname__)
  # Returning the object to which this method is bound just to ilustrate
  return command.__self__

magic(test().asdf)
```

"method of an object" = [Instance methods](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html)

Comment: Thank you for helping clarify some of my misunderstandings/bad assumptions.