# Print function name in the function itself

Tags: python, function

I have many functions like:

```
def DBworker_thatdoes_job7():
    print "DBworker_thatdoes_job7 starting..."

    ... the actual code here ...

    print "DBworker_thatdoes_job7 finished."
```

How to do this without hardcoding the function names? Here is what I want to achieve:

```
def DBworker_thatdoes_job7():
    print thisfunction.name + " starting..."
    ...

def DBworker_thatdoes_cleaning18():
    print thisfunction.name + " starting..."
    ...
```

Note: I've already looked at [How to get a function name as a string in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/251464/1422096) but I don't really see a nice way to do it here. Also, this question is close to [Determine function name from within that function (without using traceback)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5067604/determine-function-name-from-within-that-function-without-using-traceback) but here applied to the specific use case of function-name logging at startup and end, thus not exactly a duplicate.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Determine function name from within that function (without using traceback)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5067604/determine-function-name-from-within-that-function-without-using-traceback)

Comment: If you use the `logging` module to produce this type of output, you can use the format string `'%(funcName)s ...'`, and the logged message will include the name of the function.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you could use a decorator:

```
def start_finish(f):
    def new_f(*args, **kwargs):
        print("starting", f.__name__)
        f(*args, **kwargs)
        print("finished", f.__name__)
    return new_f

@start_finish
def function():
    print('function body')

function()
```

this prints:

```
starting function
function body
finished function
```

Comment: Very nice solution! The first time I really see the benefits of decorators and will finally use them :)

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps a decorator?

```
def log_function_start(fn):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        print '{} starting...'.format(fn.__name__)
        fn(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper

@log_function_start
def DBworker_thatdoes_job7():
    ...
```

Comment: Very nice solution too!

Answer (score 0):

You have more leeway to customize your function if you manually implement a callable, i.e. by creating a class with a `__call__` method.

```
>>> class foo(object): # or class foo: in Python 3
...     def __call__(self):
...         # your logic goes here
...         print(type(self).__name__)
... 
>>> foo = foo()
>>> foo()
foo
```