# How can I parse a class attribute for its name?

Tags: python, python-3.x, parsing

I apologize if my terminology is incorrect. I am trying to get the name of the function from an API return. For example, the following is what is returned from an API. How do I get the name, `the_function`?

```
my_variable = <Function the_function(str,int,uint)>
```

The `type` of the above is:

```
type(my_variable) = <class 'the_class.utils.datatypes.the_function'>
```

If I only have access to what I have shown, how to I the text string `the_function`? Is there an easy way to do it besides turning it into a string and using regex or something similar?

Comment: `foo.__name__` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get a function name as a string in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/251464/how-to-get-a-function-name-as-a-string-in-python)

Comment: If I do `my_variable.__name__`, I get 'the_function' object has no attribute '__name__'

Comment: Did you tried to print its `dir` to see what all are its attributes?

Comment: @Abdul Niyas P M Ahhh that has the answer. There is a `function_identifier` in the `dir` that gives me what I need. Is this normal?

Comment: You can't do `my_variable = <Function the_function(str,int,uint)>`, this is not correct syntax. `<Function the_function(str,int,uint)>` means nothing to python on its own

Comment: @python_crypto_questions Yes. Always use [dir](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#dir) if you have no idea what all are the attributes does the object have.

Answer (score 1):

Use `__name__` argument:

```
def yourfunction():
    pass

print(yourfunction.__name__)
```

Then now you'll get expected output.

Comment: If I do `my_variable.__name__`, I get 'the_function' object has no attribute '__name__'

Comment: @python_crypto_questions See: [someone answers my question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to that function through literally any variable, you can use  `.__name__`:

```
 >>> def the_function():
...     pass
... 
>>> the_function.__name__
'the_function'
>>> foo = the_function
>>> foo.__name__
'the_function'
```

Comment: If I do `my_variable.__name__`, I get 'the_function' object has no attribute '__name__'

Comment: @python_crypto_questions What's `variable` in that context?

Comment: @python_crypto_questions please accept the answer if it was useful