# Is there a way to identify a functions name from within the function?

Tags: python, function

Is there a way to find a functions name from within the function?

```
def some_function():
    function_name = ... # some way of retrieving the name 'some_function'
    print(function_name)
```

The expected value of `function_name` would be the string: 'some_function'

Comment: Take a look for [How to get a function name as a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/251464/how-to-get-a-function-name-as-a-string)

Comment: `inspect.currentframe().f_code.co_name` seems execute the fastest

Answer (score 0):

some_function.__name__ should work

Comment: In which case you may also simply use `'some_function'`…