# How to get a method name in Python

Tags: python-3.x, function, methods

I've been trying to get a method name within this method. I found similar question on stack about getting name for [function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/251464/how-to-get-a-function-name-as-a-string) but solution there did not help

Example:

```
class Test():
    def meth(self):
        print(meth.__name__) # doesn't work
        print(neth.func_name()) # doesn't work either
        return 0
```

These cases worked with function but in method I can't even call `meth.something`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Determine function name from within that function (without using traceback)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5067604/determine-function-name-from-within-that-function-without-using-traceback)

Comment: `self.meth.__name__` or `Test.meth.__name__`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @AChampion pointed out the solution is

```
self.meth.__name__
```

Or can be used

```
Test.meth.__name__
```

Comment: Yes, `meth` exists in the `Test` class scope. From other scopes (insides of methods of the class are other scopes too) you need to use the dot notation: `Class.class_attribute` or `object_instance.class_attribute`. Here `Class` is `Test` and `object_instance` is `self` (automatically given as parameter to methods).