# Get name of function passed as callback or similar event/interrupt handler?

Tags: python-3.x

When you pass a defined function as a callback or event/handler function, say to a thread or multiprocess object, can you get the actual name of the function in executed function?

For example, if I pass `Test`, (i.e. `def Test()`) to some Python object that needs such a callback during initialization, can I get the name of the function to print before I invoke it? Name from the passed object itself.  I tried using __str__ and __repr__, but both return a full descriptor of the pass (function) object... '<function OnProcess..Test at 0xb33f9390>'.  I could just parse the string removing '<function', '', and at '0xb33f9390>' elements of string representation of the passed (function) object, ending up with 'OnProcess.Test'.  But is there a better way?  More elegant way to get just the function name?  Can't use inspect module because I have not called the function as yet, so no stack frame, it is just a parameter value at the point I want to get the name.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get a function name as a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/251464/how-to-get-a-function-name-as-a-string)

Comment: Keep in mind that there are callable objects other than functions - instances of a class with a `__call__()` method, for example.  If you get too specific with your code to extract a name from the callable, you might needlessly disallow the user from passing such an alternative value.

Comment: @enzo, I don't believe so... since I am trying to get the name of an object that does not yet exist in any frame available, when I inspect the stack.  The context of a method at the time I need the name, it is just an object reference, yet to be invoked.

Comment: @jasonharper, yes, true.  However, my need is just for logging/execution trace logging.  I wanted to use 'Process.Test' as more human understandable, readable, than <function OnProcess..Test at 0xb33f9390> for example.

Comment: @Schorschi You don't need to inspect the stack, that's only one of the 13 answers of the linked question. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47155992/9997212) does what you want, so yes, it does answer your question.

Comment: @enzo, do you mind illustrating how? I realize everything is an object in python, so get that there has to a reference to the 'name' of the object in some place, no doubt, I just am not seeing it as yet.

Comment: In the same way you're calling `__str__` on the object, just call `__qualname__`.

Comment: Ah, nuts... I was way over thinking this.  Thanks.

Comment: No problem, pal. I still love you.