# how to get function's name from within the function (or kind of "self" reference to the function)?

Tags: python

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/251464/how-to-get-the-function-name-as-string-in-python/255297#255297) shows that there is a built-in `__name__` attribute of a function which can be used from **outside** the function, i.e. `print f.__name__`. However, how can I get this attribute from **within** the function itself?

Just using unqualified `__name__` does not help: `print __name__` prints `__main__`.

Using `print f.__name__` from within `f()` looks stupid - I can type `"f"` just as well.

Alternatively, is there a kind of `self` object for functions, i.e. can I get a pointer to the function that is executing in a common way?

I don't like the method proposed in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/245304/how-do-i-get-the-name-of-a-function-or-method-from-within-a-python-function-or-me) - it feels that hacking the stack for such simple task is not the proper way.

**Motivation**: I have a dictionary of `{keyword:function}`, the keywords are read from the input and an appropriate function is executed. I want each function to be executed only once, so I want each function to register itself in some data structure when executed. I know I can do it in the dictionary itself, but I thought of using a separate data structure for this.

Python version is 2.6.4 BTW

Comment: Just link to this answer, which solves the questions in the title: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5067654/547578

Comment: thanks @fossilet but as I say in the question playing with the call stack for this feels... don't know, too hacky

Comment: I find it humorous that you find inspect to be "too hacky". Granted the syntax of navigating the multi-dimensional stack probably warrants reading the docs, but it's effective. Here's another hacky one that might be fun: pass the function as an argument to itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps you should decorate each function that you're calling with an `onlyonce` decorator? That would be more pythonic. A proof of concept follows.

```
called = set()

def onlyonce(fn):
    def decorated(*largs, **kargs):
        if fn not in called:
            called.add(fn)
            print "Calling"
            fn(*largs, **kargs)
        else:
            print "Already called"
    return decorated



@onlyonce
def test_function():
    print "I am getting called now"


test_function()
test_function()
test_function()
test_function()
```

Also, functions are "immutable" and can be stored as dictionary keys. You don't have to rely on the names. This might be an advantage (or a disadvantage) depending on your use.

Comment: thanks, Ibrahim. Do you mean by your last paragraph that I can do `called[f]=True`?

Comment: Yes but I use sets instead of dictionaries since you don't have any "value" to store with the key.

Comment: This does not answer the question in the title though.

Comment: It answers the question that should have been asked instead which is often more useful.

Answer (score 4):

if you don't want to "inspect" the stack, you could use a decorator on your method to store it in your dictionnary and avoid to launch it twice.

```
function_list = []
def method_singleton(function):
    global function_list
    def decorated_method(*args, **kwargs):
        if function.__name__ not in function_list:
            function_list.append(function.__name__)
            return function(*args, **kwargs)
        else:
            print "Method %s already called"%function.__name__
    return decorated_method

@method_singleton
def method_to_decorate(arg1, arg2):
    pass
```

where "function_list" is the list of functions already called (i don't know how you manage your dictionnary)

Comment: now that I know about decorators thanks to your answers :), doesn't your solution check the `function_list` only once, when the the function is defined and decorated? Shouldn't the check be dynamic, every time the function is executed?

Comment: oh, yes, you're right ;) to do it at call, you'll have to move the test into the decorated method