# what is the best and general way to refer a function's __name__ in a function?

Tags: python, python-3.x

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I get the name of a function or method from within a Python function or method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/245304/how-do-i-get-the-name-of-a-function-or-method-from-within-a-python-function-or-me)

The below code function return it's name.
It works but I still have to specify the 'test.' in front of of the `__name__`.
Is there any general way to refer the `__name__` ?

```
def test():
   print test.__name__
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to access the function name in a python function without using a backtrace.

```
In [1]: import inspect

In [2]: def test():
   ...:     print inspect.stack()[0][3]
   ...:

In [3]: test()
test
```

So, what you want to use is `inspect.stack()[0][3]` or, if you want to move it into a separate function, `inspect.stack()[1][3]`

(from [How do I get the name of a function or method from within a Python function or method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/245304/how-do-i-get-the-name-of-a-function-or-method-from-within-a-python-function-or-me))

Answer (score 3):

If I understand correctly - [Inspect](http://docs.python.org/library/inspect.html) is what you are looking for.

```
import inspect
def test():
    print inspect.stack()[0][3]
```