# Get function name as a string in python

Tags: python, function, introspection

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I get the name of a function or method from within a Python function or method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/245304/how-do-i-get-the-name-of-a-function-or-method-from-within-a-python-function-or-m)
>   [How to get the function name as string in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/251464/how-to-get-the-function-name-as-string-in-python)

I have a function named **func**, I'd like to be able to get the functions name as a string.

pseudo-python :

```
def func () :
    pass

print name(func)
```

This would print 'func'.

Comment: Wanting to know the name of a function is often a sign of a suboptimal design. Why do you want to know the name it was defined with? How will you use it? Do you understand that a function is an object and can be treated like any other value in Python?

Comment: In most cases I'd agree with you. In my particular case however, I was making a tool which would print out certain information about an arbitrary function. I wanted to have the name of the function in the print out. It wasn't in any form of structural position.

Comment: This isn't always bad.  unittest, for instance, uses the names of functions to detect which should be run.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

That's simple.

```
print func.__name__
```

EDIT: But you must be careful:

```
>>> def func():
...     pass
... 
>>> new_func = func
>>> print func.__name__
func
>>> print new_func.__name__
func
```

Comment: Also, a handy tip: simple questions like yours can very easily be answered by using the `dir` built-in function. e.g. `dir(func)` returns a list, with `'__name__'` as one of the items.

Comment: +1 on the answer for the comment

Answer (score 2):

Use `__name__`.

Example:

```
def foobar():
    pass

bar = foobar

print foobar.__name__   # prints foobar
print bar.__name__   # still prints foobar
```

For an overview about introspection with python have a look at http://docs.python.org/library/inspect.html

Answer (score 2):

A couple more ways to do it:

```
>>> def foo(arg):
...     return arg[::-1]
>>> f = foo
>>> f.__name__
'foo'
>>> f.func_name
'foo'
>>> f.func_code.co_name
'foo'
```